# Why does Visual Studio create a website Solution in the Project directory and the website in the Websites directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

When creating a website in Visual Studio 2010 (I think 2008 had the same behavior): File > New Website, VS creates the solution files in the Projects directory and the website in the Websites directory. What is the purpose? Why not just create the solution files under the Websites directory?

Comment: If you don't like this, then don't use web sites. Use File->New Project instead.

Comment: OK, but I'm confused by the layout of the types of projects. I want to experiment with the Dynamic Data Entities web site, and I can't figure out how to create one of these from within a Web Application. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can add on the website solution more project on other directories.

Also its not good to place the solution to the website directory and make it public.

Answer (score 1):

The solution files just store a user's preference and is not required parts of a website.
Microsoft does a very good job to separate them with a web site. You can delete the solution file but the web site still can be opened without problem.